# extending protected functions boost::python

Tags: boost-python, extending-classes

I have C++ code (not mine, so it is not editable). Problem is with extending protected functions and class.

```cs
#include "ExtraClass.h"
...
MyClass::MyClass()
{
...
protected:
    bool Func{}
    ExtraClass m_Foo;
...
}
```

**I need access in Python to m_Foo methods and protected functions like Func()** like

```
from MyClass import  *
bar = MyClass()
bar.m_Foo.Run() //something like this
```

but have an compiler error:
    *error: ‘ExtraClass MyApp::m_Foo’ is protected*

PS. If I change protected with public (just for try). I can access *m_Foo* only in readonly mode:

```
class_<MyClass>("MyClass", init<>()) 
    .def_readonly("m_Foo", &MyClass::m_Foo)
```

Changing to *def_readwrite* went to compiler error:

> /boost_1_52_0/boost/python/data_members.hpp:64:11: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘*(((ExtraClass*)c) + ((sizetype)((const boost::python::detail::member`<ExtraClass, MyClass`>*)this)->boost::python::detail::member`<ExtraClass, MyClass`>::m_which)) = d’

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You should provide more detail with an example that people can actually compile (so as to generate your exact error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if you want to wrap protected members, then you need to derive a (wrapper) class from the parent that makes the members public.  (You can simply say `using Base::ProtectedMember` in a `public` section to expose it instead of wrapping it).  You will then have wrap it normally.  Like this:

```
class MyWrapperClass : public MyClass {
  public:
    using MyClass::m_Foo;
};
```

In this particular example (which is really not fully baked), if you want to access m_Foo, then you need to wrap ExtraClass.  Assuming that you have The problem with readwrite is likely the implementation of ExtraClass (which probably doesn't supply a operator= that you can use).